# Monitor big text file for change and show what was added

Tags: python, python-3.x, observers

I try to monitor text log file for changes and want to see lines that was added

I try with watchdog it seems to work with some manually created/edited files for testing, but my log file (in the same directory) isn't detected as "changed", but it was changed. It's probably because this file is already open (maybe in a specific mode). If I close the app that uses this log file and change it manually then watchdog works ok.

How do I check if the file was changed and if the changes were written to 
 the console?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(f'event type: {event.event_type}  path : {event.src_path}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='C:\gory\parcienaszklo\logs', recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: Is `logs` the name of the file or the directory? Adding to a file doesn't modify the directory, you need to observe the file itself.

Comment: Also, either use a raw string, escape the backslashes, or use forward slashes in the pathname.